# jquery $("#dropdown").val does not fire when .change

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am writing a simple webpage which has two dropdown list with ages, say both of them contains options from 1 to 30. I want dropdown 2 to change to the value user selected for dropdown 1. For example, in the first place, the two dropdowns are all having 1-30 as values and defaults are both 1. An user chooses 12 from the first dropdown, I want the second one to automatically change to 13.

So I figured this javascript snippet out,

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selectfromage").change(function(){
            var fromage=$("#selectfromage").val();
            $("#selecttoage").val(fromage);
            alert(fromage);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the behavior is kinda weird, if I select a value from dropdown1, the alert fires but the .val does not. But if I refresh the page, dropdown 2 changes to the value in dropdown 1 automatically.

Please help.

Here is the snippet in my php source

```
<select name="fromage" id="selectfromage" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
<script>
        $("#selectfromage").change(function(){
            var fromage=$("#selectfromage").val();
            $("#selecttoage").val(fromage);
        });
</script>
<select name="toage" id="selecttoage" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mPCfd/ I think it works.

Comment: Yes, it works in fiddle. I think maybe the reason it is not working in my code is because I am using Symfony2 + twig and I put the javascript in a twig .html.twig. The same code just not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can select second drop value one greater then the first.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ncZTD/)**

```
$("#selectfromage").change(function() {
    var fromage = $("#selectfromage").val();
    alert($("#selecttoage option").length);
    if (+fromage < $("#selecttoage option").length)
        $("#selecttoage").val(+fromage + 1);
    else 
        $("#selecttoage").val(fromage);
});​
```

Comment: I think this should be the right way, but it is not working in my code. The two dropdownlist were using jQuery Mobile framework, does it matter? Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Put code only when dom is ready,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#selectfromage").change(function(){
   var fromage=$("#selectfromage").val();
   $("#selecttoage").val(fromage);
 });
});
```

or put code below the elements you are accessing, like this,

```
<select name="fromage" id="selectfromage" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="toage" id="selecttoage" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<script>
    $("#selectfromage").change(function () {
        var fromage = $("#selectfromage").val();
        $("#selecttoage").val(fromage);
    });
</script>
```